# how to make sure bash shell safe

Tags: bash, shell

descript:
a user uses my web function and submit some information,
I make this information  as params for the bash shell.
e.g:
   .xx.sh "$1"

how to make the $1 to be safe?

I write a bash to receive some params which submited by user,then make a interest video.
Below is my excute execution.

`./batch.sh  "img--/tmp/0528e687-4431-4aed-ba0d-5cadb624855e/modal13-02.jpg--${subtitle}" sDir--/videoTpl/18 ePath--/end-shu-default.mp4 distDir--/tmp/0528e687-4431-4aed-ba0d-5cadb624855e aPath--/tmp/0528e687-4431-4aed-ba0d-5cadb624855e/6353e35e-687e-45d6-b03a-bdf6030e427c.mp3`

The subtitle may dangerous, i want to make it be safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "slove"? What is a "web function"?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Quoting it as you are is the *right* thing to do, but as far as safety goes, it depends on what `xx.sh` is actually doing with the value.

Comment: @melpomene I updated the question, web function is what one people enter web page and input some words and submit those words to my server.

Comment: @chepner i use ffmpeg to make some materials into a video. materials is  subtitle and music and image and  video.

Comment: @chepner I understand what you mean, I will solve it. My shell is the key. Thank you.

Comment: My recommendation is to not involve the shell in anything web or CGI related.